# The -d option format of the Bash command date

Tags: bash, date

In `date`'s man page：

```
-d, --date=STRING         display time described by STRING, not 'now'
```

Sounds like you should input a exact date, but I find `date -d "-1 day"` works.

I just want a list of the format of `-d option` of the command `date`. I googled, but find none.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man date`:

> **DATE STRING**
>
> The  --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string
>   such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or
>   even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating
>   calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time,
>   relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning
>   of the day.  The date string format is more complex than is easily
>   documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

Then you can get more info and examples typing

```
info date
```

Which you can find in [Date input formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats).

> A date is a string, possibly empty, containing many items separated by
>   whitespace. The whitespace may be omitted when no ambiguity arises.
>   The empty string means the beginning of today (i.e., midnight). Order
>   of the items is immaterial. A date string may contain many flavors of
>   items:
>
> - calendar date items
> - time of day items
> - time zone items
> - combined date and time of day items
> - day of the week items
> - relative items
> - pure numbers.

Comment: Apologies if you already knew, but it refers to the GNU "info" command (in linux) : `info date`

Comment: Yes, @OlivierDulac, I just discovered it :)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to list just a collection of what you can use with date -d:

- (last|next) (second|minute|hour|day|month|year)
- X (seconds|minutes|hours|days|months|years) ago, where X=...,-1,0,1,2,3,...
- X (second|minute|hour|day|month|year) , where X=...,-1,0,1,2,3,...
- yesterday, tomorrow
- @XXXXXXXXX, where XXXXXXXX seconds since epoch

Answer (score 0):

You can access its docs by

```
man date
```

You can even do this:

```
date -d yesterday
```